# Nonblocking Webservice endpoint with JBoss6 and CXF Continuation API

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, jax-ws, cxf, servlet-3.0

I am currently trying to setup a webservice endpoint  (within an JBoss AS 6.1.0.FINAL enviroment) to enable clients to long-poll for serverside events without blocking listener threads at the serverside.

Since there does not seem to be a standard solution I found this [blog post](http://sberyozkin.blogspot.com/2008/12/continuations-in-cxf.html) about CXF continuations (which beside is the WS-Impl. in JBoss).

I could transfer the example as JAX-WS

```
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.xml.ws.BindingType;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceContext;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.MessageContext;
import org.apache.cxf.continuations.Continuation;
import org.apache.cxf.continuations.ContinuationProvider;

@BindingType(javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING)
@WebServlet(asyncSupported = true, urlPatterns = "/LongpollWebservice")
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://longpoll.edu/", name = "LongpollWebservice", serviceName = "LongpollWebservice", portName = "LongpollWebservice")
public class LongpollWebserviceImpl implements LongpollWebservice {

    @Resource
    WebServiceContext ctx;

    @Override
    @WebMethod
    public List<EventBase> getEvents(String topic, Date since) {
        final ContinuationProvider cp = (ContinuationProvider) ctx.getMessageContext().get(ContinuationProvider.class.getName());
        final Continuation c = cp.getContinuation();
        if (c.isNew()) {
            c.suspend(10000);
            return null;
        } else {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
    }
}
```

The Continuation API comes from

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

This is a reduced example. The invocation of `c.suspend(10000);` should mark the current servlet invocation as State.SUSPENDED. After ten seconds, the suspension should timeout and the request should be reinvoked with `c.isNew() == false`. (In a real world example the Continuation could be passed to an JMS-Listener Bean or stateful CDI-Eventlistener and `c.setObject(event); c.resume();` would be called by the event-dispatcher once an event is available and ready to be delivered)

The CXF interceptor chain should interrupt the executing thread with an `SuspendedInvocationException` and reschedule the webservice invocation.
It compiles and deploys fine on a JBoss 6.1.0 FINAL so far. The wsdl is perfectly delivered.

**BUT:** when I call getEvents() from a Webservice-Client, the `SuspendedInvocationException` does not seem to be caught correctly. The whole invocation crashes with the following stacktrace:

```
14:39:59,578 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/longpoll-warfacade].[edu.hsos.dwe.wss.longpoll.warfacade.LongpollWebserviceImpl]] Servlet.service() for servlet edu.hsos.dwe.wss.longpoll.warfacade.LongpollWebserviceImpl threw exception: org.apache.cxf.continuations.SuspendedInvocationException
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:258) [:2.3.1-patch-01]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:113) [:2.3.1-patch-01]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletDestination.invoke(ServletDestination.java:97) [:2.3.1-patch-01]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:461) [:2.3.1-patch-01]
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.ServletControllerExt.invoke(ServletControllerExt.java:172) [:3.4.1.GA]
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:57) [:3.4.1.GA]
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.transport.ServletHelper.callRequestHandler(ServletHelper.java:156) [:3.4.1.GA]
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFNonSpringServletExt.invoke(CXFNonSpringServletExt.java:90) [:3.4.1.GA]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:179) [:2.3.1-patch-01]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:103) [:2.3.1-patch-01]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [:1.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:159) [:2.3.1-patch-01]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:324) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:63) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:274) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:181) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.event(CatalinaContext.java:285) [:1.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(CatalinaContext.java:261) [:1.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:88) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:100) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:159) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.request.ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.invoke(ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.java:53) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:654) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:951) [:6.1.0.Final]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [:1.6.0_18]
```

So finally my question: Is there anyone who has experience with CXF Continuation and WS and can give me a hint what could be wrong with this attemp?

I do not really get why the Exception is rethrown in [PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/maven2/org.apache.cxf/cxf-api/2.2.3/org/apache/cxf/phase/PhaseInterceptorChain.java#243).

Kind regards,
avithan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

1. Install CXF 2.3.4 to jboss/common/lib (we need this issue fixed: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-3362).
2. JBossWS-CXF does not catch `SuspendedInvocationException`. This seems to just been left out in jbossws-cxf-server. I filed an issue at https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBWS-3409. The attached patch can easily be applied to a checkout of jbossws-cxf-3.4.1.GA (module jbossws-cxf-server) and recompiled with `mvn package`.

Kind regards